# Is there a way to use a value in a JSON array (or any array for that matter) as an argument within a KQL query?

Tags: arrays, kql, azure-sentinel

EDIT:

Let me try to make it more helpful.

I run a general query that contains, as part of the results, the aforementioned JSON Array:

```
My_workspace
| where ArgumentOne == "ThisIsArgumentOne"
| project Time, ArgumentOne, Data_Set_One
```

So i get many results and one of them reads like this:

| Time | ArgumentOne | Data_Set_One |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-01 12:00:00 | ThisIsArgumentOne | ["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"] |

After getting my results i want to search for everything that contains one of the values from Data_Set_One as a parameter in Data_Set_One

e.g from my original query something like

```
My_workspace
| where Data_Set_One contains <INSERT COMMAND HERE> ["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"]
```

Again, even a way to look for an item within an array, having to modify the JSON entry in some way would be welcome.

Comment: Please share the full scenario, including a data sample, and not jut your attemted solution.

Comment: Not so helpful. Please supply us with a detailed example.

Comment: Hey, I edited the main question to make it a bit easier on the eyes. 10x

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this, using `toscalar()` and `has_any()`:

```
let values = toscalar(
    My_workspace
    | where ArgumentOne == "ThisIsArgumentOne"
    | project Data_Set_One // assumption: this is an array of type `dynamic`
    | take 1
);
My_workspace
| where Data_Set_One has_any(values)
```